# DIY laser range-finder

Tags: photodiode, laser, light-sensor, laser-diode, photosensor

I would like to develop a laser range-finder board similar to [Extech DT300](http://www.extech.com/display/?id=14432). I would like to achieve a centimeter precision at 20 meters.

[image]

I don't know if devices such as DT300 use a "standard" time-of-flight approach (delta time between emission and reception) or a phase-shift time-of-flight approach (continuous emission, phase shift detection).

Question #1: Could [ISL29501](http://www.intersil.com/content/intersil/en/products/optoelectronics/proximity-sensors/light-to-digital-sensors/ISL29501.html) achieve a similar precision? Datasheet is available [here](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl2/isl29501.pdf). The idea would be to use a laser emitter / receiver like [here](https://wholesaler.alibaba.com/product-detail/Laser-sensor-four-sets-of-laser_60454440162.html).

[image]

Question #2: Should I use another chip to drive the laser emitter / receiver in a "standard" time-of-flight approach as described above?

Comment: 325 mA drive seems adequate for limited ranges of 50m with the optimal,PD

Comment: DYI? Do yourself in?

Comment: Title changed for typo...

Comment: It does not use time-of-flight if you can afford it. It uses interferometry and a fixed (precision) light guide length inside it as a reference.

Comment: @winny, Do you know of some place (link) that describes the theory of operation in more detail?

Comment: The datasheet provided a bit of information about this modulated indirect time of flight. Seems like a very good compromise to get 80% of the performance of a true time of flight for 1% of the cost.

Comment: @winny this data sheet http://www.extech.com/resources/DT300data.pdf ?  Or the user manual? http://www.extech.com/resources/DT300_UM.pdf  Neither tell me very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired 10mm precision might be a bit optimistic. Here is the *typical* performance of their [eval board](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl2/isl29501-st-ev1z-user-guide.pdf) with a ~2m range. It's not obvious to me how this changes when you increase the range.

Presumably there is a hard limit of ~33m due to the modulation frequency, but that's within your desired range.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the eval kit datasheet. But they are using an IR led. I guess that "most" of the precision comes from the emitter and the receptor, doesn't it? For sure, it would be very different with a laser. It seems difficult to know without testing...

Comment: Hard to say. You are talking 67ps for 1cm (2cm round-trip) a lot of things could contribute to that.

Comment: I don't think this last comment is correct. ISL29501 doesn't measure the round-trip time to the target. It measures a shift in the phase.

Comment: @JohnSmith How would you  distinguish (say) a 370° phase shift from a 10° phase shift?